# Comparing Bmp, JPEG, PNG, TIF files

Tags: delphi, bitmap, compare, jpeg, filestream

I need a e method which compares content of two files together, files can be BMP, JPEG, PNG, TIF 
I tried this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 f1, f2 : TFileStream;
 Bytes1: TBytes;
 Bytes2: TBytes;
 i: integer;
 s: booleAN;
begin
 f1 := TFileStream.Create('C:\Output\Layout 1.JPG' , fmOpenRead);
 f2 := TFileStream.Create('C:\Data\Layout 1.JPG' , fmOpenRead );

 if f1.Size <> f2.Size then
 begin
   ShowMessage('size');
   exit;
 end;

 SetLength(Bytes1, f1.Size);
 f1.Read(Bytes1[0], f1.Size);

 SetLength(Bytes2, f2.Size);
 f2.Read(Bytes2[0], f2.Size);

 s:= true;
 for I := 1 to length(Bytes1) do
 begin
   if Bytes1[i] <> Bytes2[i] then
   begin
     s := false;
     Exit;
   end;
 end;

 if s then
   ShowMessage('same');
end;
```

but this is not working fine for me my files are both the same in content but their size are different in 2 byte.

one of the files is the on that I have to give to user the other one is the files that user is opening the same file and make a copy of it, so why they are 2 byte different i have no idea but they should be away to compare content of these files

Comment: Have you checked what the Cmd-line utility  FC.Exe reports the differences to be?

Comment: since MS Office 2007 the files are basically ZIP files. So, just unzip them both and compare internal content with tools like WinMerge or Aracis or any other file comparer

Comment: My guess is the difference is because of the SVN one files is in svn and the other one not

Comment: my files are image files so why MS OFFICE?

Comment: The question title says power point.....

Comment: I edit the question I'm so sorry :D

Comment: I reverted your edit. I don't want this to turn into a debugging session. My answer corrects the one defect in your code.

Comment: ok can you please post a reliable code for comparing this please? that can help me a lot

Comment: I did. You change the for loop as I said.

Comment: well i have to comment the size checking part, but seems like the files are really different! because the different byte is 12963!

Comment: Again, I explained this in my answer. JPEG is lossy and does not round trip load/save

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:"I reverted your edit."  Not meaning to be controversial but I think the OP should be allowed to correct the inconsistency as he sees fit, not be forced a accept an edit to suit a posted answer.  Natural justice and all that ...

Comment: @martyn interactive debugging isn't really the deal here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Sorry, I was meaning simply the inconsistency between the types of file in the q title and its body.  I don't have an opinion on the substance of the q: for all I know, the OP might be trying to find out if two files are semantically the same even if they are physically different.

Comment: @martyn yeah, that's fair enough, I was too lazy to do a partial revert

Comment: If the sizes are different then the files ***are different***. Even if the first `n-2` bytes are identical, the larger file has 2 extra bytes where the smaller file has nothing. Stubbornly refusing to accept that the files are different is an exercise in futility.

Comment: well yeah actually the files are really different, couple of pixels inside of image are different so i have to fix the creating of the file then i think this code is gonna work fine, thank you all you really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The code has one error. Dynamic arrays are zero based so the loop should be:

```
for I := 0 to high(Bytes1) do
```

The code is very inefficient. It should not read all the content at once. And you should use `CompareMem` to compare blocks of memory.

You say that the files have different size, but you expect them to compare equal. Well, that makes no sense. Your code explicitly checks that the sizes match, as it should.

Opening and reading a JPEG file will modify the content because JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm.

Your subject suggests that you wish to compare PowerPoint files but the files are in fact JPEG images.

Comment: I wan to compare power point to but for now i the images are much more important for me.

Comment: Fine. I answered the question you asked all the same.

Comment: all the files have 2 byte difference so checking the size right now makes no sense

Comment: The files are different then aren't they.

Comment: @TinaSoltanian Assuming that two different files of a different size are the same as each other makes no sense. If the sizes do not match, then they are not the same file. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to compare JPEGs you probably need to include a range, something like

```
Const 
   DELTA = 2 ;

if (Bytes1[i] - Bytes2[i] > DELTA) OR (Bytes1[i] - Bytes2[i] < -DELTA) then
```

Comment: well why do i need a range? because of jpeg file structures?

Comment: Because JPEG compression alters the image. Even recompressing the same image with the same parameters can produce rounding errors.

Comment: An arbitrary tolerance on each byte comparison won't compare the images for similarity rather than equality.

Comment: Yes, but I have to be simple to illustrate.

Comment: I doubt that comparison of individual byes would make any sense on DCT compressed binary data, jpeg is not bitmap.